# Yeoman application - using custom nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am starting a development of `node.js` & `anular` application using `Yeoman` tool for all its awesomeness (or so they say) but I am wondering about one thing.

After my application is generated there are some task defined for grunt, for example server which I can start to serve my application.

Everything looks fine if I would want only client-side of the application to be developed but what about integrating some custom `node.js` server file that would contain some server-side logic if I would want to develop web-application using full javascript stack?

What is the best way to integrate custom `node.js` server into `Yeoman` managed application? (I generated mine using `angular` generator)

Comment: If you're going to be using Express, try [this generator](https://github.com/gonzaloruizdevilla/generator-angularexpress).

Comment: I am not planning on using Express for now, just some basic node server I can customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some quick research I have done and what I would do.  I would integrate yeoman/grunt with Express a Connect/Node.js based application server.  Hey I think grunt server etc even comes with it!  They you have reference static content and dynamic serverside app type stuff quite easily.  Example, junk code:

```
app = require('express').express();
app.use('/', connect.compress());
app.use('/', express.static('static/root'));
app.use('/urlfornodestuff', YOURFANCYAPP);
```

Start here as part 2 talks about how to do this: 
http://arvelocity.com/2013/05/04/running-an-express-server-with-grunt-and-yeoman-part-1/

In part 2:

> Now your Express server is running from  server.js with a minimalistic client-side app, and with tests! Expand on it to your heart’s content and watch happiness spread out across the land.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will take a look, I hope that I can somehow make it work w/o using express framework because I did not intend to use it in my project. I just wanted to have an option to develop simple node.js server for my application and use it with Yeoman

Comment: Really express is just connect which is just node.js all with layers nice stuff.  From the sounds of the article it seems you already are.